# How to know if a Turing Machine is a decider?

Tags: turing-machines

Is there an easy way to approach this? Can I find if it is a decider by looking at the diagram of the Turing Machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decider is a machine that halts on all inputs. [There is no general way to prove whether a given machine halts on all inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

If you have a specific machine, you can try to formally prove that all paths of execution halt. For example, if your machine's read head always moves right on each transition (never left), and halts when there is no more input, then for all finite inputs the machine will halt. A simpler example would be a machine that has only one state: halt.

Comment: I am little confused about infinite input. If the infinite input keeps the Turing Machine changes between two states and both states are not accepting state and rejecting state, is this Turing Machine a decider?

Comment: @FrankJoe There's no such thing as infinite input. Every input must be finite. Additionally, if the TM is running forever, then it's not a decider. It must eventually hit Accept or Reject and then stop moving (Note that a TM will never continue to move after it hits one of those two states, by definition).

Answer (score 0):

TM  decides language L iff
1- the strings L put M into the Accept state
2- the strings NOT IN L put M into the Reject state

TM M recognizes language L iff
1- the strings L put M into the Accept state
2- the strings NOT IN L
  - EITHER put M into the Reject state
  - OR cause M to loop

@Wanhui Qiao 
you are saying "TM changes between two states and both states are neither accepting nor rejecting states, is this Turing decidable?"
then it is definitely going infinitely i.e it is going into loop which is Turing recognizable.

Comment: You probably need to edit and rephrase in order to make more obvious how your text actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove in general that

```
DECIDER_tm = { <M> : TM M is a decider } is undecidable.
```

Prove by contradiction. Assume it is decidable and let `R` be a decider for `DECIDER_tm`.

Construct `S` decider for `HALT_tm` using `R` as a subroutine .

```
S = on input <M,w>
1. construct M_w = " on input x" 
    run M on w
    if M accepts accept. if M rejects reject.
2. Run R on M_w
3. If R accept => accept, if R rejects => reject.
```

Note that if `M` accepts or rejects `w`, `M_w` halts on all input, `R` accepts since `M_w` is a decider. If `M` loops on `w`, `M_w` loops on all input, `R` rejects `M_w`.

We have built a decider for `HALT_tm` since we know `HALT_tm` is undecidable our assumption was wrong => `DECIDER_tm` is undecidable.